# discord.py-rewrite - How to use custom checks in cogs?

Tags: discord, discord.py

So, on my `bot.py` main file, I have:

```
class Bot(commands.Bot):

    # BOT ATTRIBUTES

    class default_cooldown:
        maxcommands = ...
        seconds = ...
        mode = ...

    class my_exception(commmands.CommandError): pass

    def my_check(self):
        def predicate(ctx):
            if ctx.author in a_list: return True
            raise self.my_exception

bot = Bot(...)
```

Now I also have a cog file where I want to use the `Bot().my_check()` check and my `Bot().default_cooldown()` class:

```
class Cog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @self.bot.my_check()
    @commands.cooldown(self.bot.default_cooldown().maxcommands, self.bot.default_cooldown().seconds, self.bot.default_cooldown().mode)
    async def a_command(self, ctx):
        pass
```

But I get an error, saying that `self` is not defined on my check and cooldown. Can anyone please help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are created once when the class object is created, not individually for each instance.  You have a couple of options:

1. Factor out the code that need to appear in both places to a third module that contains just that code, then import that into both of your other files
2. Move your `Bot` definition into a separate module from the execution of your bot, and make `my_check` a `staticmethod`.  Then you can access it through `Bot.my_check` instead of through the specific instance.
3. Define your cog inside `setup` so that the class is aware of the `bot` instance when it is created.

Comment: Is it possible to write your check without `bot` at all?  The cleanest way would be to have just `def my_check...` in the file, without a class or involving `bot` at all.

Comment: If possible I would move both of those out of your main file as well.  None of your other files should rely on things being imported from the main file (you might want to read about circular dependencies to see why).  Implicitly inheriting them by passing `bot` around is also not a great solution.  Better to have them in a third place where they can be imported by both the main files and the extensions.

Comment: Not necessarily.  What exactly are you worried about?